# Counting the number of letters/digits

Tags: c++

My goal is to write a C++ program that can read a text file and:

- Count the average number of letters/sentence.
- Count the total amount of digits.

The text file would be read with command "./a.out < textfile"

What I've tried so far is to have the program check each character at a time with "cin >> current". I have a while loop. If current hits a punctuation mark, it should increase linecount by 1. It should also be reading for alpha characters, but I'm not sure how to make it count those.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int letters; //Total number of letters per sentence                                                                                                                              
  int digits; //Total number of digits                                                                                                                                             
  int sentencecount; //Number of sentences                                                                                                                                         
  float averageletters; //Average number of letters per sentence                                                                                                                   
  int linecount ; //Count of lines                                                                                                                                                 
  char current; //Current character                                                                                                                                                

  cin >> current;

  digits = 0;
  letters = 0;
while (cin)
    {
      if (current == '.' == '!' == '?')
          linecount++;
          //calcuate averages and other sentence data                                                                                                                              
          //reset sentence data                                                                                                                                                    
          if (isalpha(current))//repeat for digits                                                                                                                                 
        letters++;
          cout << "line #" << letters << endl;
        cin >> current;
    }                                                          

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `current == '.' == '!' == '?'` is a big ask, no? Lots of funky conversion stuff going on there, which the compiler will deal with, although not in the way you'd expect. And respect to the indentation!

Comment: So I should split it into three different sections?

Comment: You increase the line counter when you encounter punctuation, and output `letters` with the label "line #". Words are important. They have meaning. Don't make things harder for yourself by ignoring what words mean. Make things easier for yourself by first solving the problem of counting just the characters without classifying them.

Comment: if (current == '.')
          linecount++;

if (current  == '?')
          linecount++;

And so on?

Comment: duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676000/read-number-of-lines-words-characters-from-a-file), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42079334/c-program-need-lines-words-and-characters-count), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775602/im-counting-the-number-of-characters-in-a-file-but-i-want-to-count-the-number-of) amongst many others

Comment: @molbdnilo I don't understand what you mean. Which words am I ignoring?

Comment: You'll enjoy this task. It's *really* hard and even professional software like MS Word gets this wrong. There are so many exceptions: "I went to Westward Ho! and it was wonderful." being one of them. Plus things like "I like to pretend I'm in the S.A.S. when I'm flirting with girls." being another. Then there's the *ellipsis* to worry about: "It's the end of the world..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (current == '.' == '!' == '?')
```

The line above doesn't do what it think you does. Suppose `current` *is* a exclamation point. Then this evaluates to:

```
if (false == '!' == '?') // The character is NOT a '.'
```

Then:

```
if (false == '?') // '!''s value is > 0, so the condition checks if true == false
```

And finally:

```
if (false) // For the same reasons as above
```

To fix your condition, use:

```
if (current == '.' || current == '!' || current == '?')
```

This uses the boolean OR operator to check if any of the conditions inside the statement are true, under which case to go inside the if statement. You can also add parentheses to the condition to increase readability.

Comment: Drop the word ASCII, it's introducing unnecessary assumptions. You should say `!`s value is greater than zero. (It's not allowed to be less than zero for any encoding - I think).

Answer (score 0):

if (current == '.' == '!' == '?')

probably won't evaluate they way you intend. You might want to read up on c++ operator precendence.

You could try-

if ((current == '.') || (current  == '!') || (current == '?'))